# Is there the way to create list of Dictionary<field_name, field_value> from query results?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is there the way to create list of `Dictionary<field_name, field_value>` from query results using `NHibernate (session.CreateSQLQuery(someQuery)...)` ?

Query may be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get any row as dictionary with a transformer

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("...");

var listOfDictionaries = query
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)
    .List<IDictionary>();
```

and for query like

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT ID, LastName FROM dbo.Users");
```

we can work with first result

```
listOfDictionaries[0]["ID"] // or
listOfDictionaries[0]["LastName"]
```

*A hint in doc [16.4. Associations](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-associations)*

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy NHibernate